# async waterfall not executing next callback method when used with a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

```
async.waterfall(eventIDs.map(function (eventId) {
            console.log(eventId);
            return function (lastItemResult, nextCallback) {
                if (!nextCallback) {
                    nextCallback = lastItemResult;
                    lastItemResult = null;
                }
                // same execution for each item in the array
                var eventPromise = loadEventsData.loadFormData(eventId, apiList);
                eventPromise.then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var itemResult = response;
                    // results carried along from each to the next

                    nextCallback(itemResult, nextCallback);
                });


            }}), function (err, result) {
            // final callback
        });
```

output for `console.log(eventId)` is correct, it is printed as many times as the items are in the array. but `console.log(response)` is only printed once, meaning callback is not being called properly ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified and the issue got fixed

```
nextCallback(null, itemResult);
```